# How can I show popular posts viewed use wpbakery (VS) carousel?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I  use WPBakery page builder (VS) And as shown as I use  `tab` elements with 3 tab. First tab is top 5 posts have most comments, second is top 5 most viewed posts by users and the third is top 5 new posts.

[tab elementin vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20qqF.png)

for first and third I use carousel element and that work perfectly but in second tab how can I use carousel for show top 5 most viewed posts by users?
I install [WordPress Popular Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) but that not usable in carousel element.
How can I do this?
[element tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAN8X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install plugin with `post view counter` name after  that auto add `view counter` option to carousel. This plugin URL is `https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/`